# Text not updating on pressing button in dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Text widget and two buttons to increase or decrease the count. + button to increase the count and - button to decrease the count. And the count is displayed in a Text widget. When I debug, count is changing but the Text is not updating. Not getting any error as well. How to do this. Here is my code:

```
  _showDetails(BuildContext context, String barcodeResult) {

return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Container(
          height: 350.0,
          width: 200.0,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.teal),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 50.0,
                    left: 94.0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 90.0,
                      width: 90.0,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        ExactAssetImage(
                                'assets/images/user-image-default.png'),
                      ),

                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  description,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Price : $price',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.teal, // button color
                      child: InkWell(
                        //splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            // count++;
                            count = count + 1;
                            print(count);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(count.toString()),

                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.teal, // button color
                      child: InkWell(
                        //  splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.remove,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            //count--;
                            count = count - 1;
                            print(count);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's updating on the device also. I don't see any issue in it.

Comment: i think that you may declare and initialise count variable in build method.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad no it is not updating

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I have not declared in build method

Comment: @USER9561 Where have you declared your `count` variable?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad outside build method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Here is the working code.

```
_showDetails(BuildContext context, String barcodeResult) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return Dialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Container(
              height: 350.0,
              width: 200.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 150.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 100.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.teal),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 50.0,
                        left: 94.0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 90.0,
                          width: 90.0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage(chocolateImage),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      description,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Price : \$${price * count}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.teal, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            //splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                            child: SizedBox(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // count++;
                                count = count + 1;
                                print(count);
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(count.toString()),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.teal, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            //  splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                            child: SizedBox(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.remove,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                //count--;
                                count = count - 1;
                                print(count);
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: I am displaying this in a dialog. Is it causing issue?

Comment: Please post full code of the dialog, where exactly you're using it.